# Most efficient method of storing image in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, 2d

As I'm developing some image processing app in JAVA, I wonder which way is the fastest and less memory consuming for storing an image. So far I figured out I can do it by storing all loaded data in int[] array (of width*height length, each entry represents 32-bit RGBA color), in BufferedImage object, or in Image object. Mainly purpose of application is to transform 2D images and to perform specific structures (let's say edges, corners, etc.) detection algorithm.

Thanks in advance for every reply/comment!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294388/make-a-bufferedimage-use-less-ram) question.

Comment: However I am curious also about time consuming aspect (i.e. reading single pixel info) and processing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I started this as a comment, but it became longer and longer - maybe it qualifies as an answer.</sup>

`BufferedImage` is extending `Image`. So the main choice is between a `BufferedImage` and a raw `int[]` array.

Concerning the memory overhead of a `BufferedImage` over an `int[]` array: This should become neglibible for "reasonably large" images, because a `BufferedImage` (with `TYPE_INT_*`) does not store much more than an `int[]` array with the actual data internally. (Particularly, this `int[]` array is stored as the data of a `DataBufferInt` in the `Raster`).

Concerning the performance, there may be a noticable or even significant difference between accessing raw array elements and accessing the pixels of a `BufferedImage`. `BufferedImage`s are fast, particularly for drawing, but when it comes to computations on pixel values, nothing beats a plain, raw `int[]` array.

However, this sheds only little light at the broad spectrum of questions that may influence the final decision. For example, when you say that you want to do things like edge detection, you might notice that this functionality is already available for `BufferedImage`, as shown in the [Image Processing and Enhancement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/spec/j2d-image.html#wp63208) section of the Java2D Imaging Tech Notes. You won't be able to implement an edge detection by convolution with a sobel filter on a plain `int[]` array with *just 4 (four) lines of code*.

BTW: The tech notes in general provide some background information, and are definitely worth a look in order to make a profound decision here.

There is also an [answer on the GameDev stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75661/java-single-array-best-choice-for-accessing-pixels-for-manipulation/75667#75667) site that covers some of of the aspects that are relevant here, maybe you'll find it interesting.